# Formatting the data for a column in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a data base that holds users and their birthdays. I store the birthday in my data base as a DateTime Object.

Here is my XAML code

```
<DataGrid Name="lookAtUsers" ItemsSource={"Binding MyUsers"}>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birthday!" Binding="{Binding Birthday}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

When the DataGrid is displayed, the time is displayed with it.

There seems to be two possible solutions:

1.) Format is so that when I save this information I save a DateTime object that is formatted as MM/dd/yyyy

2.) be able to some how format the text in the DataGrid so that I can remove the time

I thought that option one would be the easiest to implement but so far I have not been able to find a solution online.

Option two is more likely a little more complicated and since I am a new C# programmer, I do not know much about DataGrids

Comment: [BindingBase.StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can format a string format of a column as the following:

```
Binding="{Binding Birthday, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}"
```

I do not really understand why this works so if anyone wants to take the time to explain or explain option 2 that would  be awesome

Comment: Agree with @Phia-CM : if you're working with WPF, you can use StringFormat property applied to the Binding